# SSIS Package errors while running from Integration Services Catalogs

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am making enhancements to an existing (probably older version) SSIS project. I have added a few packages to the project.  Some of the packages have script tasks and script components. All the new packages run perfectly on the Visual Studio on my dev machine. I have deployed the project on my integration services catalog and executed it there. This resulted in 100s of error messages. The first message at the bottom of the final page says the message type is "OnInformation". The package format was migrated from version 6 to version 8. It must be saved to retain migration changes.". The second message says which is the type  "OnWarning" says "Warning: Found SQL Server Integration Services 2012 Script Component ABCD that requires migration. There are more than 20 warnings of that sort.

Few of the OnError messages are:

- CS1056: Unexpected character '$', ScriptMain.cs, 148, 76.
- The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking edit script button and make sure it builds successfully.
- Error: Failed to compiled scripts contained in the package. Open the [aclage om SSIS Designer and resolved the compilation errors.
- Error: CS1002 - ; expected. main.cs,208, 99
- Error: CS1525 - Invalid expression term ":". main.cs, 208, 97
- Error: CS1003 - Syntax Error, ":" expected, main.cs, 204, 98

FYI: We recently updated from SQL 2012 to SQL 2019. And the package version is 2012. So that might be the issue. Should I update the package to 2019 and then try it? What could be the issue for these errors? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

My Visual Studio edition is enterprise version 2019. Version 16.11.30.  Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.03761.

I have tried deploying the 2012 version of the package and ran it from the catalog. I have run the package from visual studio.

Comment: *"We recently updated from SQL 2012 to SQL 2019. And the package version is 2012. So that might be the issue."* That is very likely the issue. Upgrade the project to 2019, and then redeploy to SSISDB. Note you may get build errors, due to the change in the .Net version for your c# scripts; if you do you'll need to address those.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Updating the solution to SQL 2019 and rebuilding it after worked like a charm. Thanks.